# Return a value from a document listener

Tags: java, listener, jtextpane, documentlistener, documentfilter

I have 2 java classes. Once adds a document listener to a doc(HTMLDoc). The other is a class that implements DocumentListener.

I want to be able to return a value to this class so I know when the document is changed so I can strip out unwanted html that is getting pasted in and causing problems with the JTextPane.

```java
doc = (HTMLDocument) kit.createDefaultDocument();
//setContentType("text/html");
doc.addDocumentListener(new CTextPaneListener());
```

This is the Listener Class

```
public class CTextPaneListener implements DocumentListener
{

    // Gives notification that an attribute or set of attributes changed.
    @Override public void  changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println("DEBUG: changedUpdate() called");
    }

    //Gives notification that there was an insert into the document.        
    @Override public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        // I want to be able to return a value or a form a detection
        // so I can tell when there has been a insert.
    }

    //Gives notification that there was a remove from the document.                     
    @Override public void   removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        //System.out.println("DEBUG: removeUpdate called");
    }
}
```

I've done a a bit of java but it's been a few years so I'm a little rusty. Thanks for your time.

Edit: this is my custom DocumentFilter, I originally thought this would catch the paste, but however only the DocumentListener seems to be catching the pastes.

```
public class CTextPaneFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    public CTextPaneFilter(Document doc)
    {
        this(doc, 0);
    }

    public CTextPaneFilter(Document doc, int maxChars) {
        this.doc = doc;
        maxCharacters = maxChars;
    }       
    /**
    * Specifies the maximum text input length of the text pane.
    */
    public void setMaxLength(int len)
    {
        maxCharacters = len;
    }
    /**
    * Invoked prior to insertion of text into the specified Document. 
    */
    @Override public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,      String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
    {
    /**
    * Teuncates the inserted string so the contents
    * would be exactly maxCharacters in length.
    */
    System.out.println("insert");

    if (maxCharacters == 0 || (doc.getLength() + string.length()) <= maxCharacters) {
                        fb.insertString(offset, string, attr);
    } else {
        if (doc.getLength() < maxCharacters) {
            fb.insertString(offset, string.substring(0, maxCharacters - doc.getLength()), attr);
        }
    //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
// other overridden methods below
```

Comment: Format your code before post

Comment: How can I answer it if I didn't even read it, and my privilege editing is not working. So, I'm unable to help you nor others to read it.

Comment: You can't return any value (even if it wouldn't be an interface) since this is going to be called be the system, and the system actually know there's an insert.

Comment: MouseEvent, I was afraid of as much, what would you suggest as a way to tackle this problem?

Comment: @Jeff Actually this question is better suited to answer for those who love `DocumentListener` but in your question it's shown badly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html). It allows you to reformat text before it is written into a document.

Comment: I actually have looked into this, for some reason in the JTextPane it's not recognizing the paste on the insert or the replace, just when text is entered via keyboard.

Comment: I added some text above to explain why this wasn't working out for me.